# Can I use different cost functions in prior( η) and posterior(τ) functiona in Ant Colony Optimization?

Tags: traveling-salesman, ant-colony

For TSP(Traveling Salesman Problem) solving by ACO(Ant Colony Optimization), I've read something like [Ant Colonies for traveling salesman problem](https://people.idsia.ch/%7Eluca/acs-bio97.pdf), [The Ant Colony Optimization Meta Heustic](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/jbollen/I501F13/readings/dorigo99ant.pdf), [aco2004.prn.pdf](https://people.idsia.ch/%7Eluca/aco2004.pdf) etc. I've got something about ACO including intuitive understanding and simple implementation, but math part.

In almost all the examples introduced, there is a function of Dij, prepresenting distance between vetex i and j, working as cost function. And this cost funtion is used in both η and τ in each iteration. Can I use different distance functions or cost functions for η and τ? For example, in a problem of searching shortest route in a special network, an assumption has been introduced as: the more out-spanning ports, the more probability of the router that would be in the shortest path. So, can I use the function of f(d, m){d: distance between vertexes, m: outspanning ports} for η and f(d){d: distance between vertexes} for τ?

In my mind, η is just a heuristic function to inject some bias in search, it could be any function valid. Is that right? I am also wondering if it (differenct cost function for η and τ) imposed some effections on validation of properties of ACO, like convergence, lower bounder etc.

Thank you very much!